# jQuery HTML CSS effects

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Is possible with the sole use of jQuery / HTML / CSS to animate a diagonal transition of block element from bottom left corner to top right. So a triangular shape fills the transition period until the block is filled?

I am after this as I have users with a browsers that do not support CSS3 transitions. Ideally this would work in both Chrome and IE8+

After time, this is what i gained:

Works in IE8+ | Chrome | Firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/yYK9b/

**CSS**

```
div.arrow {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
    border-bottom: 50px solid #bb0000; /* bottom, add background color here */
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
div.cover {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
    border-bottom: 50px solid #FFF; /* bottom, add background color here */
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}
div.topLeft {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
div.topRight {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
div.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 0px solid #bb0000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="topLeft"></div>
    <div class="topRight"></div>
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".wrap").hover(function(){
        arrow = $(this).find(".arrow");
        $(arrow).stop().animate({
            borderBottomWidth: "600px",
            borderRightWidth: "600px"
        }, 500)
},function(){
        arrow = $(this).find(".arrow");
          $(arrow).stop().animate({
            borderBottomWidth: "50px",
            borderRightWidth: "50px"
        }, 500)  
});
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Any other questions?

Comment: Yes it is possible with javascript/jQuery, but we can't do it for you. What have you tried? Without an attempt, this topic may get closed...

Comment: Dom, insightful and helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible. Let's say you have a block which is a square, with `overflow: hidden`. then you have an inner square within that one, absolutely positioned off-screen so to speak. Using the jquery animate property, you could animate the position of the inner block so it moves to position 0px/0px

I was too lazy to create an image, but you could eliminate the proprietary css rules if you used an image instead of using CSS to rotate a square like I did in the example.

Comment: Best answer and solution